# Function equivalence in simplification clarification

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, analysis, functions

This is a question to make sure about my understanding regarding simplification of equations. Assume I got $g(x)$ after simplification from f(x). Does that tell  both are equal?  I guess no .. There are cases where we get different graphs for f(x) and g(x)

**1**
\begin{equation}  
f(x) =  \frac{x^2-4}{x-2} 
\end{equation}
**2**
\begin{equation}  
g(x) =  x+2   
\end{equation}

Definition (1) and Definition(2) dont share same Domain and Range . x=2 works for Definition(2) not for Definition(1).  But we normally simplify like this.

**Doubts**

1. If we simply an equation f(x) to another g(x),can we state  we may not be getting equivalence functions always? (quite evident from the example above) NB :: equivalent means same domain and range in this context
2. If we do simplification , can we say g(x) may add more elements in range and domain?. Can we say apart from undefined  domain and range in f(x), rest of the domain and range elements in g(x) must be same with f(x)?
3. Will there be case like g(x) is more restricted than f(x) where we loose domain and range elements?(opposite of the concept)

**NB**

There are cases where we get equal graphs for f(x) and g(x) 
\begin{equation}  
f(x) =  \frac{4x^2}{2} \\
g(x) =  2x^2  
\end{equation}
and there are cases where both graphs are different as in mentioned in the first example. All depends on the whether domain and range  definition are  allowed for all elements in the function definitions . Purpose of this question is to confirm whether I am right or wrong regarding the statements above

Comment: depends on $x=2$ and $x \neq 2$

Answer (score 1):

$f(x)=\dfrac{x^2-4}{x-2}=\dfrac{(x+2)(x-2)}{x-2}, dom(f)=\{x:x\neq2\}$, when $x\neq2$, $f(x)=g(x)$, for $x\neq2$.

If we restrict the domain these two function are actually equivalent, but if you don't restrict the domain of $g(x)$, then these two function are different.

There are cases when $g(x)$'s domain becomes more restricted:

Let $f(x)=x^2=\dfrac{x^2}{1}$, $dom(f)=\{x:x\in\mathbb{R}\}$,

if we let $g(x)=\dfrac{x^2(x-1)}{x-1}$ then $dom(g)=\{x:x\neq1\}$, where the domain of $g$ becomes more restricted.